When $MN$ is the matirx of order 3 and its determinent is given how to find determinant $NM$ of the matrix of order 2
Let $M=[a_{ij}]_{3 \times 2}$ and $N=[b_{ij}]_{2 \times 3}$ be the matrices such that $(MN)^2=3MN$ and $det(NM) \ne 0$ then $det(NM)=$_______
My approach is as follow $MN$ is the matrix of order $3\times3$ and $NM$ is the matrix of order $2\times2$
Now  $(MN)^2=3MN$ is equal to $(MN)(MN-3I)=0$ hence $det(MN)=3^3=27$ but how do we find $det(NM)=$

$\det(MN) = 0$ because $MN$ has rank at most $2$.

The equation $(MN)^2=3MN$ gives
$$M(NM)N=3MN \implies  M(NM)^2=3M(NM) \implies M((NM)^2-3NM)=0$$
Now, since by assumption $\det(NM)\neq 0$ then the unique solution of the system $NMx=0$ is the zero solution, so the unique solution of the $Mx=0$ system is the zero solution too. This means that
$$(NM)^2-3NM=0  \implies \det(NM)=3^2=9.$$

From $(MN)^2 = 3MN$, we may write
$$(NM)^3 = N(MN)^2M = N(3MN)M = 3(NM)^2.$$
Since $NM$ has a nonzero determinant, it is invertible, and by multiplying this equation by $((NM)^{-1})^2$ gives $$NM = 3I_2.$$
Here we have solved for $NM$.  Finding its determinant is now routine:
$$\text{det}(MN) = \text{det}(3I_2) = 3^2=9$$
